# Counting factor instance of several columns of factors

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame along the lines of this:

```
> DF <- data.frame(V1=c("Yes", "Yes", "No"), V2=c("Yes", "No", "No"), V3=c("Yes", "Yes", "No"))
   V1  V2  V3
1 Yes Yes Yes
2 Yes  No Yes
3  No  No  No
```

No I would like to use something along the line of mutate to count the instances of "Yes" in each row to get something like this:

```
   V1  V2  V3 CountYes
1 Yes Yes Yes        3
2 Yes  No Yes        2
3  No  No  No        0
```

Is there an easy way to do it? I am sadly out of ideas.

Thanks and BW,
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on a logical matrix

```
DF$CountYes <- rowSums(DF == 'Yes')
DF$CountYes
#[1] 3 2 0
```

Answer (score 2):

That's an overkill, but since you've tagged this with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(CountYes = sum(c_across() == 'Yes'))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  V1    V2    V3    CountYes
  <fct> <fct> <fct>    <int>
1 Yes   Yes   Yes          3
2 Yes   No    Yes          2
3 No    No    No           0
```

Comment: Thank you! Akruns answer worked, but I will keep your methods in mind. They'll probably come in handy soon^^

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option (but not as simple as `rowSums` by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63403026/12158757))

```
DF$CountYes <- table(stack(data.frame(t(DF))))["Yes",]
```

which gives

```
> DF
   V1  V2  V3 CountYes
1 Yes Yes Yes        3
2 Yes  No Yes        2
3  No  No  No        0
```